# Inner Join all children top(n) parent

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

I need to do a inner join, where i Get a concrete number of "parent elements" but all it's relations.

If i have the table Agent:

```
IdAgent | Name
     1  |      Agent1
     2  |     Agent2
```

And the table Econ

```
IdEcon IdAgent Number
1 |      1 | number1
2 |      2 | number21
3 |      2 | number22
4 |      2 | number23
```

So if I do a:

```
SELECT * FROM Agent LEFT JOIN Econ
```

I Will Get 4 rows

```
IdAgent | Name | IdEcon IdAgent Number
1 | Name 1 | 1 |      1 | number1
2 | Name 2 | 2 |      2 | number21
2 | Name 2 | 3 |      2 | number22
2 | Name 2 | 4 |      2 | number23
```

But if i do a:

```
SELECT top(2) * FROM Agent LEFT JOIN Econ
```

I Will Get 2 rows and i want 4 rows (I want the top 2 only to affect the table Agent)

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the `top(2)` usage.

Comment: So what exactly is the output you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested:

```
SELECT * FROM (Select top(2) * FROM Agent) LEFT JOIN Econ
```

Answer (score 1):

You could select the top two agents separately and use the result as a derived table to join to `Econ`, as in [jarlh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27480502/297408), or you could use `TOP (2) WITH TIES` together with `ORDER BY Agent.IdAgent`:

```
SELECT TOP (2) WITH TIES
  ...
FROM
  dbo.Agent
  LEFT JOIN dbo.Econ ON ...
ORDER BY
  Agent.IdAgent ASC
;
```